# VoiceOver notifications to Braille board

Tags: iphone, ios, voiceover

I have an iPhone application with VoiceOver. I have alse connected Braille board with iPhone device. 
For VoiceOver Notification I use:

```
 UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification,  textFieldMain);
```

But in this case Braille board no get any notification.
Is there a possibility to notify Braille board from code?